# Idea + Android. Can't launch hello-world

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am a newbie in android developing and want to launch my first android app with no success:(

- I have download the IntelliJ Idea 10.5 Community Edition, Android SDK 2.2 API Version 8, java-6-sun package.
- Have install these on my laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.
- Have created the virtual device.
- Did following http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_Android_in_IntelliJ_IDEA
  .

But when I have started the application virtual device launched, the device's operating system  started, desktop appeared and nothing more. The Idea run window is showing the text

```
Waiting for device.
```

I don't know how to fix it. Where I am wrong so the application doesn't launch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you can communicate with it by using `adb` from your command line.

```
adb devices
```

should show your virtual device there.

```
adb shell
```

should let you a shell on that device.

If all that works, then I don't know (it works just fine for me)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the adb was not installed. After I have installed it the application launched normally. The simulator is toooo slow on my msi u120:)

Comment: You need a decent machine to run it definitely... the other alternative is to use a real Android device...